# histogram equalization for colored image give error using python opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

> Error : Assertion failed (0 < cn && cn <= CV_CN_MAX) in merge

In the merge function

```
cv2.merge(channels,img2)
```

if the arguments are replaced as shown:

```
cv2.merge(img2,channels)
```

it will not give an error, but the histograms will be the same before and after equalization. What can I do in this piece of code.

Code:

```
import cv2,cv
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
img_size = cv.GetSize(img)

width,height = img_size
size = width,height,3
channels = np.zeros(size , np.uint8) 


while (1):
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
img = np.asarray(img[:,:])

cv2.imshow("original",img)
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[2],None,[256],[0,256])

#convert img to YCR_CB
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

#split image to Y, CR, CB
cv2.split(img2,channels)

#histogram equalization to Y-MATRIX
cv2.equalizeHist(channels[0],channels[0])

#merge this matrix to reconstruct our colored image
cv2.merge(channels,img2)

#convert this output image to rgb
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)
hist2 = cv2.calcHist([rgb],[2],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.plot(hist)
plt.plot(hist2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `split` and `merge`, take advantage of numpy slicing.

```
img2[:, :, 0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img2[:, :, 0]) 
# or run a small loop over each channel
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: it is the actual solution, you just don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

you got the split() wrong here. it *returns* the channels.

since you don't catch the return values, your channels are not initialized

```
>>> import cv2
>>> help(cv2.split)
Help on built-in function split in module cv2:

split(...)
    split(m[, mv]) -> mv
```

so it should look like:

```
channels = cv2.split(img2)
```

and please, *avoid* the old cv api, instead stick with cv2 consistently. (use cv2.VideoCapture, not cv.CaptureFromCAM)

Comment: berak: This might be an inappropriate comment here but actually i am trying to learn python based opencv and i am not able to differentiate  between `old cv api` and new one...could you please tell me, how to know which one is new while checking the details of a method at opencv docs...btw i am new to python also

Comment: not at all inappropriate. cv2 is the new api(build on opencv's c++ api and using numpy arrays for images and such), cv is the old one(build on opencv's deprecated c-api) . both are essentially incompatible, and the old one won't be available in the future, so use cv2. how to know ? hmm, by the prefix, i guess ?

Comment: @berak: ok, thanks. I think that i got your meaning...we can differentiate by seeing if its `cv2` or `cv`.